# Почему бот отвечает только 1 раз и далее не работает?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
import datetime

def write_msg(user_id, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {
    'user_id': user_id,
    'message': message,
    'random_id': 44187491
})

# API-ключ созданный ранее
token = "token"

date_now = datetime.date.today()

# Авторизуемся как сообщество
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

# Работа с сообщениями
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)

# Основной цикл
for event in longpoll.listen():

# Если пришло новое сообщение
if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

    # Если оно имеет метку для меня( то есть бота)
    if event.to_me:

        # Сообщение от пользователя
        request = event.text

        # Каменная логика ответа
        if request == "привет":
            write_msg(event.user_id, "Ну привет)")
        elif request == "пока":
            write_msg(event.user_id, "Куда собрался?")
        else:
            write_msg(event.user_id, "Ни понял.")
```

Answer (score 0):

При отправки сообщения методом messages.send, параметр random_id должен быть случайная цифра(не помню точно какой диапозон, но максимальное значение это пользователи вк). И эта цифра должна быть всегда рандомная при каждой отправки.

```
import random

def write_msg(user_id, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {
    'user_id': user_id,
    'message': message,
    'random_id': random.randint(0, 100000)
})
```

Раньше можно было ставить random_id параметром 0 и работала, но сейчас это не у всех работает. Нужно читать документацию по vk api. Там все подробно и понятно написано